# Fedora 31 ignores my BTRFS mount settings

Tags: fedora, btrfs

I'm trying to convince my new Fedora 31 build to mount a particular subvolume at boot. I have the following subvolumes created:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol list /
ID 256 gen 308 top level 5 path root
ID 258 gen 196 top level 5 path home
ID 263 gen 191 top level 5 path @
ID 264 gen 304 top level 5 path @home
```

/etc/fstab:

```
UUID=61300ca8-34e9-4e83-a840-de3ae96fa9c5 /                       btrfs   subvolid=263,subvol=@     0 0
UUID=c2b244ef-ecfb-4c0f-8e6f-5f209dccf482 /boot                   ext4    defaults          1 2
UUID=61300ca8-34e9-4e83-a840-de3ae96fa9c5 /home                   btrfs   subvolid=264,subvol=@home 0 0
UUID=75205d04-dd23-46d6-aadd-6a99ddb01b6f none                    swap    defaults          0 0
```

The /home subvolume is mounting correctly, but the / subvolume is not; it always reverts to the initial subvolume that Fedora created at installation:

```
$ mount | grep btrfs
/dev/vda3 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/root)
/dev/vda3 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,space_cache,subvolid=264,subvol=/@home)
```

I have tried forcing the default subvolume with `sudo btrfs subvol set-default 263 /`, but this is also ignored.

Comment: Check your boot loader (ex. GRUB, systemd-boot). It's most likely configured to specify what to mount as the root filesystem.

Comment: I had to edit `/boot/grub2/grubenv`, now it's working. Thanks for the info!

Comment: The entry for `/` in `fstab` is partially a dummy. Compare [*How is `/etc/fstab` accessed before root is mounted?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107828/108618)