# What is the significance of GPT's "Partition Type GUIDs"?

Tags: filesystems, gpt, cfdisk

When I use `cfdisk` to create a new partition, I usually change its type to `Linux filesystem`. There's multiple types for most operating systems, but a very large number for Linux (architecture-specific for `root`, `/usr`, and something called “verity”?).

But isn't `/etc/fstab` the file that gives meaning to these partitions? Why should I make my swap partition type `Linux swap` and my root partition type `Linux root (x86-64)`?

Comment: Just FYI, dm-verity is a real thing, which adds cryptographic metadata attesting that the contents of some other partition has not been tampered with (sort of a digital signature over another partition). It's widely used by Android (and similar systems), making the system refuse to boot if anyone modifies the root filesystem but does not have the corresponding private keys to update the verity signatures.

Comment: The separate type for swap has existed for decades now, and is hardly Linux-specific. That, in particular, is used to help new installs detect existing swap space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind all these different partition type GUIDs is that they can be used to mount a system’s volumes *without* `/etc/fstab`. The partition types are defined in [the discoverable partitions specification](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/discoverable_partitions_specification/). With systemd, this is handled by [`systemd-gpt-auto-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-gpt-auto-generator.html).

The general idea behind this is to be able to build systems with no system-specific information in `/etc`, so that a single static image can be used reliably without needing any customisation. (Obviously this needs a fair bit more than partition type GUIDs, but that’s the driver.) See also [Lennart Poettering’s blog post on the topic](http://0pointer.net/blog/the-wondrous-world-of-discoverable-gpt-disk-images.html).

Comment: Once I created a *Temporary Data Partition*, then rebooted for some reason without creating a filesystem there. Not a good idea.

Comment: Gaaaa. That's crazy bad for security. I should be able to plug in a foreign disk and not get compromised by stuff on the disk I didn't even mount.

Comment: @Joshua: Don't boot from the disk. The current implementation only looks for those partitions on the same disk that contains the EFI System Partition (i.e. only if it's your boot disk).

Comment: Well my /home is on a different disk so it won't work anyway.

Comment: Wait a minute; how does systemd know which disk I booted from? grub isn't passing that to the kernel.

Comment: @Joshua, UEFI firmware sets... well, EFI variables; in Linux, they're exposed via efivarfs. Even if GRUB doesn't participate at all, the system's firmware can set EFI variables to say which device it found GRUB on.

Comment: @Joshua it’s all explained in the spec linked in the answer; see in particular [the Boot Loader Interface](https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_INTERFACE/).

Comment: LOL don't assume PartUUIDs are unique. People clone disks all the time.

Comment: LOL people ignore parts of specs all the time. (It’s neither here nor there to me, I don’t think anyone involved in this Q&A works on systemd or any of these specs.)

Comment: Possibly of interest, [ClearLinux](https://www.clearlinux.org/) is a distro that actually uses DPS as it’s default for handling disk setup, including dropping `/etc/fstab`. Having actually had to work with it, I can attest that it’s a major pain in the arse because there’s no clean way to handle things like filesystem mount options in many cases and it doesn’t play nice with LVM (you can use it to mark LVM PVs, but there’s no way to auto-discover what LV the root filesystem is on). The idea is great for appliance-type stuff or thin clients, not so much for many other types of systems.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn which is exactly what I was referring to above: the spec says “The option to drop these configuration bits is primarily something for appliance-like devices.” but that gets ignored.